# How to suppress Lint warnings in generated sources?

Tags: android, android-room, androidx, deprecation-warning, android-lint

With Room version `2.1.0-alpha04`:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha04"
```

The `@Dao` implementations of the `RoomDatabase` causes these warnings, per generated`Dao_Impl`:

```
[deprecation] setTransactionSuccessful() in RoomDatabase has been deprecated
[deprecation] beginTransaction() in RoomDatabase has been deprecated
[deprecation] endTransaction() in RoomDatabase has been deprecated
```

And also this one for the `@Database` class:

```
[deprecation] mCallbacks in RoomDatabase has been deprecated
```

The problem is, that these files are located in `mobile/build/generated/source/apt/debug`, while only paths alike `<ignore path="src/main/..."/>` seem to catch. What I've tried so far, along with absolute and relative paths and `**/` - as well as qualified class names, with and without wildcards:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="Deprecated" severity="informational">
        <ignore regexp="androidx.room.RoomDatabase" />
    </issue>

    <issue id="Deprecated">
        <ignore regexp="com.acme.database.dao.*Dao_Impl" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

How to suppress these deprecation warnings in `build/generated/source` with `lint.xml` - or is there a newer/stable version or `RoomDatabase`, which *works* (and does not cause these warnings)?

Comment: How are you kicking off the lint inspection? I am only used to running it from Android Studio, where you can specify the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Room to version `2.2.0-alpha02` removes the deprecation warnings:

```
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.6"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6"
```